# Dynamic Nested for loop using recursion (All Permutations)

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, permutation

I was trying to implement something like this.

I have bunch of lists.

Each list has certain numbers.

```
A - 1,2,3    
B - 4,5    
C - 6,7,8
```

I want to find all permutations of A, B, C list
That is:

```
1,4,6    
1,4,7    
1,4,8    
1,5,6    
1,5,7    
1,5,8    
2,4,6
and so on...
```

I could have done this using for loop, but the number of lists are not static.

So I tried using recursion.

Here is what I tried:
Calling :

```
nested(number_of_lists,0, array list of array, current_permutation);
```

And the function:

```
static void nested(int depth, int index, ArrayList< ArrayList<Integer> > list, ArrayList<Integer> curr)
{

    if(depth==0)
    {


        ArrayList <Integer> x = new ArrayList<>();
        int i;
        for( i=0;i<curr.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println(curr.get(i));

            x.add(curr.get(i));
        }
        global.add(x);

        curr.remove(curr.size()-1);

    }
    else
    {

        for(int i=0;i<list.get(index).size();i++)
        {

            curr.add(list.get(index).get(i));

            nested(depth-1, index+1, list, curr);

            if( curr.size()==list.get(index).size())
            {
                curr.remove(curr.size()-1);
            }

            if(index==0 &&(curr.size()-1) == i)
                curr = new ArrayList<>();


        }
    }

}
```

Global is new array list of array list which had all permutations stored.

But, after two permutations with A, I get wrong answer

```
1 4 6 
1 4 7 
1 4 8 
1 5 6 
1 5 7 
1 5 8 
2 4 6 
2 4 7 
2 4 8 
2 5 6 
2 5 7 
2 5 8 
2 3 4 6 
2 3 7 
2 3 8 
2 5 6 
2 5 7
```

and so on..

Where is the code doing wrong.
My first two permutations with two elements of A are perfectly fine.
Sorry for such a long explanation.
Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be making this more complicated than it actually is. I have managed to correct this just by commenting out some of your lines.

```
static void nested(int depth, int index, ArrayList< ArrayList<Integer> > list, ArrayList<Integer> curr)
{

    if(depth==0)
    {


        ArrayList <Integer> x = new ArrayList<>();
        int i;
        for( i=0;i<curr.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println(curr.get(i));

            x.add(curr.get(i));
        }
        global.add(x);

        //curr.remove(curr.size()-1);

    }
    else
    {

        for(int i=0;i<list.get(index).size();i++)
        {

            curr.add(list.get(index).get(i));

            nested(depth-1, index+1, list, curr);

            //if (curr.size()==list.get(index).size())
            //{
                curr.remove(curr.size()-1);
            //}

            //if(index==0 &&(curr.size()-1) == i)
            //    curr = new ArrayList<>();


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanx a lot. Any other way to do or is this is the best way?

Comment: There are a few improvements you can make. For example, you don't need both `index` and `depth` because they always add up to `list.size()`. Also, the whole section involving `x` can just be replaced with  `global.add(new ArrayList<>(curr));`. Finally, try to avoid global variables. Instead, just add `global` as aa parameter to the method.